# RUBY and JQUERY AJAX CALL on Heroku Sinatra app

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax

I want to execute an inline update on database records via an ajax call. Then reload the page so that the update is shown when the page is reloaded.

The ajax script is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".update").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var newdesignation =  $('#newdesignation'+ id).val();
        var newcompany =  $('#newcompany'+ id).val();
        var newphone = $('#newphone'+ id).val();
        var newemail = $('#newemail'+ id).val();
        var newremarks = $('#newremarks'+ id).val();
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/update/data",
        data: { 'id' : id, 'designation' : newdesignation, 'company' : newcompany, 'phone' : newphone,  'email' : newemail,  'remarks' : newremarks },
        success: function(){
        window.location.reload();
        }

      });
     });
})
```

and the ruby script is:

```
get '/update/data' do
dataset.where(:id => params[:id]).update(:designation => params[:designation], :company => params[:company], :phone => params[:phone], :email => params[:email], :remarks => params[:remarks])
end
```

The update executes fine but (on heroku) the page does not reload. When I run it on my local machine the page does reload.

The error I get in the console is:

```
502 BAD_GATEWAY 183ms   
jquery.min.js (line 5)
no element found
```

Any ideas what the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not triggering the success callback, perhaps because your ruby script isn't explicitly returning a 200 status code.  In Sinatra, you could change your controller code to:

```
get '/update/data' do
  status 200
  dataset.where(:id => params[:id]).update(:designation => params[:designation], :company => params[:company], :phone => params[:phone], :email => params[:email], :remarks => params[:remarks])
end
```

Note the status 200 line.

If that doesn't work, make sure you're not interrupting any other ajax requests.  Change your callback to

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  window.location.reload(true)
})
```

This will wait for your ajax calls to complete before reloading the page.

Finally, have you considered refreshing the page via the server?

You could add:  `redirect to('/bar')` to the end of your controller action which would refresh the page after the update is complete.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks, I will give it a shot. I had considered halt 200 after the dataset update (but not yet tried); reload(true) does not work and redirect/bar does not work either. I will experiment with status 200 and let you know. Many thanks. I think it's a heroku thing as it works on my local machine.

Comment: Thanks Jake, it's a bit of both. Turns out all you need is redirect '/' in the controller and window.location.reload() 'true' is not necessary, in the ajax script, then it works. Grateful for your help.

Comment: I didn't actually mean redirect to the path "/bar" in the controller.  Bar was just a placeholder since I didn't know your url.  What you did was exactly what I was suggesting.